# use lapply in multiple emmeans, error in : invalid subscript type 'S4'

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, lme4, emmeans

```
lhiry1 <- lmer(ACC ~ LR1st +(1|Subject),data = learndata_long3) # hierarchy 1*
lhiry2 <- lmer(ACC ~ LR2nd +(1|Subject),data = learndata_long3) # hierarchy 2*

onelmer=c(lhiry1,lhiry2)
onelmer1=c('LR1st','LR2nd')

for (i in 1:length(onelmer))

{onelmercontr[i]=lapply(onelmer,
function(x){emmeans(onelmer[[i]], pairwise ~ onelmer1[i] , adjust ="bonf")})}
```

the fault is :

> “Error in onelmer[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'S4'
>   Called from: is(object, "emmGrid")”

it seems my frame type has some troubles, but I could not find any reason.
please help me!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there some sample data you can provide to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Given that you are running this loop only twice, wouldn't it be simpler to just run each separately?

Comment: Thanks for your reply I did not try other data and here I have 14 times, just give a simple samples to fix it.

Comment: Right. But is there some data (can be something like `iris` or `mtcars`) you can provide so that we can reproduce your code?

Comment: I try these 2 but the data structure is not same, my data has lots of factors, and only 1 column is numeric, so I may need to think about it

Comment: You can generate your own dataset, using functions like `rnorm()` or `runif()`. What matters is being able to run your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing lapply without using the vector you iterated through, and you can only make 1 test, the lapply doesn't make senes:

```
lapply(onelmer,
function(x){emmeans(onelmer[[i]], pairwise ~ onelmer1[i] ...)})}
```

Try something below, be careful to check what you are iterating through, and make sure to give them better names that make sense (instead of onelmer1 and onelmer...):

```
library(emmeans)
library(lme4)
set.seed(111)
learndata_long3 = data.frame(ACC=rnorm(100),LR1st=sample(c("a","b"),100,replace=TRUE),LR2nd = sample(c("c","d"),100,replace=TRUE),Subject = factor(rep(1:2,50)))

lhiry1 <- lmer(ACC ~ LR1st +(1|Subject),data = learndata_long3) 
lhiry2 <- lmer(ACC ~ LR2nd +(1|Subject),data = learndata_long3) 

mdls=list(lhiry1=lhiry1,lhiry2=lhiry2)
coefs=c('LR1st','LR2nd')
output= vector("list",2)

for (i in 1:length(mdls)){
output[[i]]=emmeans(mdls[[i]], 
as.formula(paste("pairwise ~",coefs[i])), 
adjust ="bonf")
}

output

[[1]]
$emmeans
 LR1st  emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 a     -0.0836 0.150 2.73   -0.588    0.420
 b     -0.0275 0.155 3.11   -0.510    0.455

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast estimate    SE   df t.ratio p.value
 a - b     -0.0561 0.198 97.7 -0.283  0.7777 

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 


[[2]]
$emmeans
 LR2nd emmean    SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 c     -0.273 0.149 3.02   -0.747    0.200
 d      0.151 0.147 2.83   -0.333    0.635

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 c - d      -0.424 0.192 97 -2.216  0.0290 

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works! I need to better know the 'list' structure, and also the formula name should be corrected!

Comment: cool. thanks for spotting the error too. i don't mind if you edit it, but for other answers, just leave a comment and the person posting can correct it. (sometimes reviewers might see it as an attempt to reply, for your info)

Comment: in fact, I am not familiar with STACK operation, so I just redo it. And I hope I do it a right way that accepted your reply as the best answer. Thanks a lot!